# Installation of kubuntu on a MacBook Pro 3.1 not successfull

Tags: kubuntu, macbook

Trying to „clean“ install kubuntu 18.10 on a [MacBook Pro 3.1](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-15-santa-rosa-specs.html) (Core2Duo) fails with the fatal error „grub install /dev/sda failed“. I tried various installation methods from fully automatic to manual but didn‘t succeed yet.

I can only boot into kubuntu from the stick when I [modify the grubloader](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2377181&p=13817037#post13817037). Elementary or kubuntu are working quite well but any installation failed as described previously. Although the internal SSD was completely erased and formatted there seems to be an issue with partitions.

Helpful ideas are appreciated!